# Colors in a Universal App portable library?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime

My portable library defines several objects which have colors associated with them.  These colors are used in the UI layers of whichever apps use the library.  Given that all the UI-layer stuff operates with Windows.UI.Color, I'd like to store objects of that type in my portable library.  Problem is that I can't find any way to reference this Color class in the library code.

At the moment, I'm stuck maintaining colors as strings of hex ("#FF00AA"), but this means I'm parsing a string every time I want to reference the color.  Sure, I could optimize it further (caching the constructed Color object, splitting the string preemptively), but this seems silly.

How can I get the Windows.UI.Color class in a Universal portable library?

Answer (score 1):

What targets You have set in this portable library? Or is it "Shared" library for universal apps?

In the second case, its no problem use Windows.UI.Color class.
If its another portable library, set targets to Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1.
I used Color class in that library and I had no problems.